Error "Session doesn't have required client" when using refresh token to renew an access token in Keycloak with React public client having useEffect
I figured out this error in my case, and just want to document it.
Similar problems

What does "Session doesn't have required client" mean?: not the bug encountering in this case, I believe
Why invalid_grant error with "Session doesn’t have required client"?: revoke refresh token is disabled in this case
https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/27384: bug revolving CORS issues, I believe

Environment

React Vite: template React + TS v5.3.1
Keycloak (KC): running on Docker, v25.0.1

Problem
I need to implement OAuth 2, specifically the Authorization Code Flow and the Refreshing an Access Token Flow. First, I created a React public client, and ran a default KC instance, acting as my authorization server. The AuthZ Code Flow worked fine, and I received all the necessary data, including an access token and a refresh token.
To perform the next flow, I sent a POST request to KC's endpoint /token with the urlencoded body as grant_type=refresh_token;client_id=clientIdHere;refresh_token=refreshTokenHere, as instructed in here. For some reason, KC refused and returned an error like this:
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "Session doesn't have required client"
}

KC Image setup

Revoke Refresh Token disabled
Only Standard Flow
Use Refresh Token

Code
# running the default KC instance
docker run -p 8080:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin quay.io/keycloak/keycloak start-dev

# useEffect code
const navigate = useNavigate();

useEffect(() => {
    const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const authZCode = params.get("code");

    const fetchDataToLS = async (codeHere: string) => {
        const tokenRes = await axios.post<TKCTokenResponse>(
            import.meta.env.VITE_KC_SERVER_TOKEN,
            new URLSearchParams({
                client_id: "myclient",
                code: codeHere,
                grant_type: "authorization_code",
            })
        );

        const { access_token, refresh_token, id_token } = tokenRes.data;
        localStorage.setItem("access_token", access_token);
        localStorage.setItem("refresh_token", refresh_token);
        localStorage.setItem("id_token", id_token);
        navigate("/protected");
    };

    fetchDataToLS(authZCode!);
    callTime++;
}, [callTime, navigate]);


From what I could gather, there are 2 main reasons causing this error:

the auth_code-token exchange function is written inside useEffect, which will make a second run if in React Strict Mode
OAuth 2, by proposed standard, will deny and revoke the authZ code, if the client (my React public client) use the code more than 1 time, AND also revoke  all tokens previously issued from that authZ code

As I was testing KC, my code was still in development mode, hence the double run from useEffect, which are captured like this, regardless of the order of those requests. And because React used the same authZ code a 2nd time, which might be the main reason, making KC denied and revoked that code, thus the refresh token associated with that authZ code would not be valid anymore.
To fix this, you could try to add logic so that the exchange should be run one time only, though I'm not sure this is an optimal solution.
